# jQuery selector working but it is not affecting the image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to show small image of width 250px by using jQuery. I tried to set the width of the image, in jQuery I have use this command. here is my jQuery code, even after giving this command image comes with its original size, i.e.600px etc etc...

My html td tag shows this value, but not affect the image.

So can anyone tell how to set the size of image so that what ever its original weight and height but its shows the with of 250px?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> </script> <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("table td #n1WPQ4").css("width","250px")

 });
</script>
```

My HTML code after applying above script.

```
 <table class="ms-formtable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td nowrap="" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
<nobr>Picture</nobr>
</td>

<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px" id="n1WPQ4" style="width: 250px;">

 <img src="http://img.dashtees.com/mini-gloves/pakistan/pakistan.03.jpg" alt="">&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel">
<nobr>Name</nobr>
</td>
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px" id="n2WPQ4">
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://sharepoint/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?  PageType=4&amp;ListId={06ABE63D-FD6E-4EC6-A473-  CF648BE5B384}&amp;ID=2&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100C0EFC789E8F94545923F62567A0C1A52"  onclick="EditLink2(this,7);return false;" target="_self">glove</a>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td nowrap=""  valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>Description</nobr></td><td valign="top"  class="ms-formbody" width="400px" id="n3WPQ4"><div dir="" class="ms-rtestate-field"></div>&nbsp;</td>  </tr><tr><td nowrap="" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>Article</nobr></td><td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="400px" id="n4WPQ4">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: `<td ... width="400px" ... style="width: 250px;">` doesn't help. The CSS will win but it's confusing to humans.

Answer (score 0):

`td #n1WPQ4` will select child element under `td` with id `n1WPQ4`.

Since you've assigned `id="n1WPQ4"` to your `td` then you don't need space here.

Also, `id` is unique so you can change your selector to:

```
$("#n1WPQ4 img").css("width","250px")
```

Comment: i have tried this, its not working, first it was showing the changed in inspect element now it has no effect...

Comment: i am doing this work in the SharePoint list, in SharePoint Designer, when i give alert query it runs, but when when i apply image size, it does not work, can any one tell what will be the issue???

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting image using selector, `#n1WPQ4` is parent id of image tag.You should use:

```
$("#n1WPQ4 img")
```

or

```
$("#n1WPQ4").find("img")
```

Comment: you are saying to use it like this  $("#n1WPQ4").find("img").css("width","250px")

Comment: ya. or `$("#n1WPQ4 img").css("width","250px") `

Comment: it not working for me, dont u think it need full path like $("table td #n1WPQ4 img").css("width","250px")

Comment: i do not think that is necessary when only one element have id `n1WPQ4 `

Comment: ok, then why it is not changing the value as it was changing before, even it was not effecting the image but it shows that it is touching is the image.

Comment: i am doing this work in the SharePoint list, in SharePoint Designer, when i give alert query it runs, but when when i apply image size, it does not work, can any one tell what will be the issue???

Comment: can you create problem fiddle??

Comment: sorry i cant, but i can answer your query about the code.

Comment: that may not help. Above code should work correctly. Fiddle would have pointed to cause of problem.